# ImportError: No module named cElementTree - Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I am getting following error while running yum on RHEL. Based on my search on google it seems it is related to python.

anyone has any idea?

```
Plugin "refresh-packagekit" can't be imported
Loaded plugins: security
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in 
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)

......
........
...........

    self.parse(srcfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repoMDObject.py", line 140, in parse
    parser = iterparse(infile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 1169, in cElementTree_iterparse
    _cElementTree_import()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 1164, in _cElementTree_import
    import cElementTree
ImportError: No module named cElementTree
```

Answer (score 1):

If its Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3

Solution:

> The libexpat.so.1 symlink links to libexpat.so.1.5.2 in /lib64/. But
>   the directory was renamed to libexpat.so.1.old. Recreating the symlink
>   with the correct name solved the issue:

```
# ln -s libexpat.so.1.5.2 libexpat.so.1
# /sbin/ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Bug 694812](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694812). I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: No, not helpful in this case.

Comment: If you have Oracle installed: http://serverfault.com/questions/482280/rhel-6-x-yum-gives-importerror-no-module-named-celementtree-errors